# How to modify the keys and values of an encrypted app.config file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, encryption, app-config

I am very new on c#/Visual Studio and I'm having difficulty on running my test methods. It requires us to connect to a database server resulting of getting always a failed result since we can't connect to the database.

We tried to modify the connection string to include our working credentials so that we can connect to the database server but the app.config file was encrypted.

Please see below screenshot of example encrypted line. How can we modify that?

[image]

Comment: This does not look like the default encrypted .config of the Framework, you should ask for details how to encrypt your credentials or have them encrypted for you. You might try to supply a simple (clear text) ConnectionString to see if the app autodetects encryption - many solutions encrypt on startup.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it I think the connectionstring is encrypted outside the project and pasted here. I am saying this because IMO encrypting just the connection string `value` and keeping the `key` in plain text is not possible from within the project. It is possible to encrypt the entire section within a config file.

Check the method which is using this connectionstring. I believe The method might be using some form of decryption. Use that to decrypt the string, change the values as required, encrypt it again and paste it in the above location.

You can also edit your question to include the method which is using the connectionstring so that I can analyse it and give you a better solution.

Hope this helps.